# Vim: Colorscheme not displaying correctly in Terminal

Tags: vim, terminal, macvim, iterm

I just made the switch to the Solarized colorscheme for Vim, however I am having some trouble getting the colors to display correctly. A more correct description would be to say that they don't look even remotely alike.

Here's a comparison:

### MacVim

[image: MacVim]

### Vim in iTerm2

[image: Vim in iTerm2]

As you can see, the difference is **day and night.**

My iTerm2 Terminal settings:

[image: iTerm2 Terminal Settings]

I would think that this allows my terminal vim to use all the necessary colors required to properly display the Solarized colorscheme, but obviously I am wrong. Anyone got an idea?

Comment: Don't bother with that stupid colorscheme, it is too unstable and full of hacks and, despite the fluffy science displayed on his site, the author is completely lost. There are hundreds of alternatives out there that will work without requiring anything else than `:colorscheme colorscheme_name`.

Comment: Also, this is a question for the plugin's issue tracker, not for stack overflow.

Comment: Did you load the `.itermcolors`? https://github.com/altercation/solarized/blob/master/iterm2-colors-solarized/README.md

Comment: Hey guys! I tried everything in the post you mentioned and none of it worked, which is why I am here. But I guess you have a point, if I have to mess around real and dirty to even make it work, I may be better off switching. Thanks for the replies, please close this question. :)

Answer (score 5):

`set t_Co=256` helped me when TERM system variable was configured to xterm-256color. Later I changed $TERM to screen256-color and VIM started to show 256 colors automatically.

Comment: thanks, setting `set t_Co=256` in `~/.vimrc` do the trick for me.